# Adding structs to a list and getting correct output

Tags: c, list, struct, typedef

I'm trying to create a struct typedef `movie_t` and add it to a list. It contains a title, director, rating, and year made. My code is only outputting the title though.  I don't understand why it's not outputting all members of the `movie_t` struct?

For example, I have defined:

```
movie_t *first_movie = {"The Outsiders","Francis Ford Coppola",'PG13',1983}
```

But when I run my program it only outputs the title:

```
list[0] = The Outsiders
list[1] = The Outsiders
list[2] = The Outsiders
list[3] = The Outsiders
list[4] = The Outsiders
list[5] = The Outsiders
list[6] = The Outsiders
list[7] = The Outsiders
list[8] = The Outsiders
list[9] = The Outsiders
```

**basiclist.h**

```
#ifndef BASICLIST_H_
#define BASICLIST_H_

typedef struct node {
  void * data;         /* pointer to data */
  struct node * next;  /* pointer to next next node */
} node_t;

int list_add(node_t ** list, void * data);

#endif
```

**movie.h**

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define MOVIE_H
#define SIZE_LIMIT 25
#define RATING_SIZE 5

typedef enum {G, PG, PG13, R} rating_t;

typedef struct {
    char rating;
    char title[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char director[SIZE_LIMIT];
    int year;
}movie_t;


void get_movie(movie_t * movie);
void print_movie(const movie_t * movie);

#endif /* MOVIE_H */
```

**main.c**

```
#include "movie.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "basiclist.h"

int list_add(node_t ** list, void * data) {
  int ret = 0;
  node_t * newnode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if (newnode == NULL) {
    ret = -1;
  }
  else {
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = *list;
  }
  *list = newnode;
  return ret;
}

int main (void)
{
  int ii;
  movie_t * new_movie;
  movie_t *first_movie = {"The Outsiders","Francis Ford Coppola",'PG13',1983};
  node_t * list = NULL;
  node_t * curr;

  for(ii=0;ii<10;ii++) {
    new_movie = (movie_t *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *new_movie = *first_movie;
    list_add(&list, new_movie);
  }

  ii = 0;
  curr = list;
  while (curr != NULL) {
    printf("list[%d] = %s\n", ii, *((movie_t *) curr->data));
    ii++;
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  printf("It worked!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how `malloc()` works? Why are you `malloc()`ing twice?

Comment: Firstly, `'PG13'` - why a multi-char character constant suddenly? Secondly, your `printf` is deliberately crafted to output only one string - it has only one `%s` specifier. Read the doc on `printf`.

Comment: I'm new to C.  I guess that is my question. How do I modify it so that it outputs title, directory, rating, year?  I have tried reading on it and changing it around.  If I no longer make 'first_movie' a pointer, it outputs the director instead of the title.  I didn't think about the rating.  I have changed it to a char[] thanks for pointing that out.  If I remove malloc() from note_t I receive compilation error and if I remote it from new_movie I receive segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("list[%d] = %s\n", ii, *((movie_t *) curr->data));` : `movie_t` and `movie_t*` are not fit  `%s`. you make custom print function(**print_movie**) for `move_t*`.

something such as

```
void print_movie(FILE* fp, const movie_t *m){
    static const char *raiting[] = { "G", "PG", "PG13", "R"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", m->title, m->director, raiting[m->rating], m->year);
}
```

change prototype `void print_movie(const movie_t * movie);` to `void print_movie(FILE* fp, const movie_t *m);`
or change name and call from `print_movie`.

at main

change `printf("list[%d] = %s\n", ii, *((movie_t *) curr->data));`
to `print_movie(stdout, curr->data);`

---

Also
change `movie_t *first_movie = {"The Outsiders","Francis Ford Coppola",'PG13',1983};`
to `movie_t first_movie = {"The Outsiders","Francis Ford Coppola", (char)PG13, 1983};`

and

change

```
typedef struct {
    char rating;
    char title[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char director[SIZE_LIMIT];
    int year;
}movie_t;
```

to

```
typedef struct {
    char title[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char director[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char rating;//or rating_t rating;
    int year;
}movie_t;
```

and

```
for(ii=0;ii<10;ii++) {
  new_movie = (movie_t *) malloc(sizeof(int));//int !!
  *new_movie = *first_movie;
  list_add(&list, new_movie);
}
```

to

```
for(ii=0;ii<10;ii++) {
  new_movie = malloc(sizeof(*new_movie));
  *new_movie = first_movie;
  list_add(&list, new_movie);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I have two questions about this though.  1. When I run my original code above on Windows I receive segfault, but I get output I pasted on Ubuntu.  Why is that difference?  2. I'm new to C, I don't quite understand the use of `FILE* fp`, can you please clarify?

Comment: @mdo123 1) It is just lucky. undefined behavior is undefined behavior. 2) in case you need to output to file.